# fsck(file system check) in WSL(Windows Subsystem for Linux)

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, fsck

How to check integrity of the root file system?

/etc/fstab says it's ext4, and /etc/mtab says it's lxfs.

Is there fsck for lxfs to run on the unmounted root from outside?

Or chkdsk in windows is sufficient for WSL files?